# How to create an ID starting from 1, which after sorting starts over each time another (string, time) variable increases by 1 (minute)?

Tags: python

As you can see here [Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv3m6.png), I have four variables. Each ID represents a section of a road, which has a speed recorded at every timestamp. However, this section has 16 subsections with each their own speed. These 16 speeds have been created as one column with 16 rows instead of 16 columns, but the IDs just go from 1-16 over and over making them non-unique.

What I need is to create a unique ID starting from one, that means that for each time stamp I have (# of IDs * 16 subsections) IDs. 
**In other words, if it is sorted by time stamp, then ID then subsection, I need it to create an ID from 1 that starts over from 1 every time it increases by one minute.**

I hope some of you can help me with this. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What library are you using for the tables?

Comment: I'm using Spyder, but the answer from the other user actually helped. Thanks for taking your time to review my question though!

Comment: Spyder is an IDE, not a library for tabular data. Were we expected to guess that you're using Pandas? Also, the accepted answer is needlessly complex, all you need is `df["uniq_ID"] = (df["ID"] - 1) * 16 + df["segment"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, here's an example - you could alter the new_id line if you want a different format.

```
def make_id(row):
    new_id = (row['ID']-1)*16 + row['Segment']
    return new_id

df['UniqID'] = df.apply(make_id, axis = 1)
```

The output would be 1 for Section 1, Subsection 1, 16 for Section 1, Subsection 16.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this out. I'm trying to understand your output. Would it then be (for a given time stamp) 17 for section 2, subsection 1, 32 for section 2, subsection 16, and would this numbering system start over when the timestamp changes?

Comment: Correct - it ignores timestamp, and just assigns the new unique id value on the basis of the section / subsection.  So for section 2, subsection 1, and no matter the timestamp, it will have the same unique ID value of 17, which I think is what you want.

Comment: Hmm, this created a variable identical to the "Segment" variable.

Comment: For the first ID number it will be the same as the segment variable, because the ID number is 1, we're taking 1 - that, and then adding the Segment number.  Is that happening for ID values 2+?

Comment: Upon a closer look, I notice that for ID 2, it goes from 2-17 over and over and for ID 3 it goes from 3-18 over and over, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a dummy, I edited the code to fix that - now increments up by 16 each time the ID number increments.

Comment: Amazing! That worked, thanks! And you're not a dummy!

Comment: Why use `apply()` for this, instead of taking advantage of broadcasting?